# Left Outer Join possible?

Tags: odbc, progress-database

i have a problem which needs to get resolved and i hope some of you can help.

i have an article table (Table A)

```
Article     Description
A43234      desk 
A42323      paper
A43235      chair
```

and a attribute table (Table B)

```
Attribute      Article      Value
height         A42323       120cm
width          A42324       200cm
material       A42323       wood
price          A43235       chair
```

not every article has an attribute in table B.
But if there is a material attribute entry for an article of Table A then it should be in the result. If there is no material attribute entry then it should be an empty string.
The result should be:

```
Article      Attribute        Value
A42323       paper            wood
A42324       desk             ""
A42325       chair            ""
```

My idea:

```
SELECT a.Article, a.Description, a.DLV, b.Value  
from tableA a 
join tableB b
on a.Article     = b.Article 
and b.Attribute = 'material'
```

Thanks!

Comment: What if there are two rows with `'material'` and the same artcicle?

Comment: But you are right, you only need to change the join to left:  `from a left join b on ..`

Comment: two rows with 'material' is not possible. they are unique. but i can be, tha there is no row for this article. so will a left join work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want material record for every article even if such record is not present in attribute table.

You can split your select to 2 parts:

- material in one - to get material for all articles
- all other attributes in second

Then you can do UNION:

```
SELECT
    a.Article,
    a.Description,
    'material' AS Attribute,
    COALESCE(b.Value, '') AS Value
FROM article AS a
LEFT JOIN attribute AS b ON a.Article = b.Article
                             AND b.Attribute = 'material'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    a.Article,
    a.Description,
    b.Attribute,
    b.Value
FROM article AS a
LEFT JOIN attribute AS b ON a.Article = b.Article
                             AND b.Attribute <> 'material';
```

Output:

```
Article     Description Attribute   Value
A43234      desk        material    ""
A42323      paper       material    wood
A43235      chair       material    ""
A43234      desk        NULL        NULL
A42323      paper       height      120cm
A43235      chair       price       chair
```

I used T-SQL and also changed JOIN to LEFT JOIN as pointed in comments, because you loose articles without attributes.

Comment: here it is for aliases only, if a string is a keyword in t-sql it is good practice to use these brackets, you can ignore them

Comment: T-SQL uses them, I don't know Progress

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way, simply change your JOIN by a LEFT JOIN

```
select a.Article, a.Description, a.DLV, b.Value  
from tableA a 
left join tableB b
    on a.Article     = b.Article 
    and b.Attribute = 'material';
```